# How to keep focus on input field (any HTML fields) after page gets refreshed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

My Requirement : Suppose I have 3 field on my form and after filling 1st & 2nd field from that 3 fields, suddenly Page get refreshed so after that the focus should be on that 2 field only.

** If any one have this solution with the "Type Script" it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store each field for the form in a query/route param so that it will fill on refresh, then do focus the first one that has no value.